# How do I remove collections in similar name quickly with mongo script

Tags: mongodb

Suppose I have thousands of collections

```
user_01
user_02
...
user_9999
```

what if I need to drop the collections between **user_77** to **user_1082**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following:

```
for(var i=77; i<=1082; i++)
{ 
    db["user_"+i].drop(); 
}
```